# Failed to delete a file in Azure File Share, Error: The specified resource is read-only and cannot be modified at this time

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

While trying to delete a file in the Azure Storage File Share. I continuously get following error:

> Failed to delete file
> 'cs-firstName-lastname-domain-com-10033fff99999999/mslearn-my-app-folder-word-and-word-wd/.git/objects/pack/pack-someguid.idx'.
> Error: **The specified resource is read-only and cannot be modified at
> this time**

Tried to check if there are any current open handles but I see none.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-handles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults>
    <Entries />
    <NextMarker />
</EnumerationResults>
```

Also, I tried to connect to this Azure file share from Windows by running powershell cmdlet **New-PSDrive**, but there too and using **Remove-Item**, getting below error

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item
Z:\mslearn-my-app-folder-word-and-word-wd/.git/objects/pack/pack-someguid.idx: **You
do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation**.
```

Any help, about how to change the property from read-only/ how can I delete/  or anything which I am missing.

Thanks,

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fde433a-aef0-49e9-8568-2aaf5a9b673a/unable-to-delete-a-file-from-azure-file-storage?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: The file is most likely locked by another process.

Comment: @DanielBjörk yes, that was the thought when tried to list handles. Any other way ?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT yes, I had stumbled on it and thats why  tried the new-psdrive , a script is provided from within azure portal.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT I will try to change the file attribute once mounted. earlier I was directly issuing a delete command. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT. Once the share was available i used ATTRIB command to change the read-only attribute. And it worked.

Comment: @PrerakK Glad to know. Thank you for sharing your solution with the broader community.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link shared by @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fde433a-aef0-49e9-8568-2aaf5a9b673a/unable-to-delete-a-file-from-azure-file-storage?forum=windowsazuredata The read-only attribute can be removed only once mounted, I did following.

1. Mounted the File Share using the script provided in the Azure portal
2. Once mounted, doing a *ls* command will show the file attributes
3. In powershell or CMD change the file attribute. I found it hard to do it via powershell so instead used ATTRIB cmd. attrib *pack-someguid.idx -R*

#### Update :  Easier Solution

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share-with-file-explorer